# Bind to a value that will be fetched from an API

Tags: ember.js

I have an endpoint that returns a list of artists (json data).
And an endpoint that returns a specific property given an id.

What I would like to do is to iterate through all the artists and display one or more properties in the template to the user but the property should only be fetched from the API if it is bound in the template.

In my ArtistsRoute, I set the model to be all those artists fetched by calling getJSON...

I want, somehow to be able to fetch a property for an artist and display it (through binding).

The Properties map could be stored in the ArtistController maybe.

I could not find a good example for this. Any help is appreciated!

Template example:
Name is on the artist object itself, but the Properties object has been created manually. So in the ArtistController it could be initialized to empty:

```
Properties = {}
```

And then it sets Propertes['ShortName'] = to the fetched value.

```
<ul>
{{#each}}
  <li>
    {{Name}}
    {{Properties.ShortName}}
    <img {{bind-attr src=Properties.MainImage}} />
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Should I use a function instead as a property or a Handlebars helper? Like:

```
{{Property this 'ShortName'}}
```

where 'this' is the ArtistController and 'ShortName' is the property to fetched. The property id can be calculated through the ArtistController and propertyName.

```
function(tag, propertyName) {
  Ember.$.getJSON('/Properties/' + tag.Id + '_' + propertyName).then(function(response) {
    var propertyValueToBind = response.Value; // This is the value I want to display in the template.
  });
}
```

Then the Property function has to know when to rerender the template (once the property has been fetched from the API).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'll want to generally avoid properties that are uppercase.  They are usually considered global properties, and not in scope.

Ember lazy loads computed properties by default, so adding that functionality to a computed property would be an excellent way to go.

```
someProperty: function(){
  var promise = Ember.$.getJSON('/Properties/buildupurl');
  return Ember.ObjectProxy.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin).create({
    promise: promise
  });
}.property()
```

Then in your template someProperty would be accessed like this

```
{{someProperty.value}}
```

And would be asynchronously populated.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/769/edit

Comment: Maybe he wants to use the `unknownProperty` too, so he can build a generic way!

Comment: @Krutius is right, I do not want to hardcode a function per possible Property, it is impossible too since a property can be created through our CMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot kingpin2k for your help and time! Very helpful!

Comment: I would like to actually have a dictionary for each artist so that I can easily bind to different properties. That is why I was thinking of creating an Ember Handlebars helper.

Comment: @user2050434 just use a normal object and the `unknownProperty`. U get a `key` parameter into that function. Do evething else lik in @kingpin2k answer.